# Why my branches are always "out-of-date", even with regulars "pull"?

Tags: git, push, branch, pull

I have 3 branches : "dev", "test" and "main". They are protected, I can't push directly on them.

When I develop something, I have to create a new branch (example : new-feature). Then, pushing on it, and doing pull requests from "new-feature" to "dev", from "dev" to "test", and from "test" to "main".

Regularly, When I try to do my PR from "dev" to "test", I've got "This branch is out-of-date with the base branch".
How can I avoid it ?

I tried to pull my 3 branches before create my new one from "dev", but it seems that's not enough : the PR to "dev" is OK, but it doesn't work from "dev" to "test" (same from "dev" to "master") because of this "out-of-date" problem.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you have setup the branches to require that source branches have the lastest version of the target branch... from your workflow description, that won't hold water for `test` and `main` Check your settings in your provider (that's not a git thing).

Comment: Yeah, that's correct, but I can't change those settings though... I can fix this by doing some merges and rebases, so git can solve this issue. I'm searching a better way to do it, before the error occurs.

Comment: oh... do _not_ rebase long running branches (like `test`, `dev`, `master`) or you will be going to the infraworld of version control (you have been warned). You could do merges in the opposite direction _first_ and then you create the PR from `dev`to `test`.... but it sounds like an overkill.... if you're _supposed_ to not do merges directly into `master` and `test` (and you have those branches protected to not accept direct pushes, right?), then there is no need to request that on those branches as you should go into `dev` instead (that branch _might_ be ok to have that flag setup).

Comment: Thanks, I can't do otherwise than rebasing right now because of my "out-of-sync" issue, that's why I'm searching another solution to do before asking my pull request ^^'

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Don't worry about it.

If you're constantly merging `test` into `main`, unless you **always** use a fast-forward merge, the `main` branch is always going to have extra merge commits in it that `test` doesn't. It's just bound to happen. Sometimes a fast-forward merge is called rebase-and-squash, but I can't recommend it when merging long-lived side branches like in your case.

When you see this message, you should ignore it.

[image: screenshot from github.com of a pop-out message on a Pull Request page: "This branch is out-of-date with the base branch / Merge the latest changes from main into this branch. This merge commit will be associated with ." with a button labelled "Update branch"]

Clicking the <kbd>Update branch</kbd> button from the Pull Request page merges the target branch into the source branch. E.g. The PR that merges `test` into `main` would merge `main` into `test`, violating your intended flow of merges.

Since you're using a branching strategy that closely resembles ["gitflow"](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow), merges should ideally only flow one direction. Clicking <kbd>Update branch</kbd> violates that flow.

### More on branching strategies from the perspective of a contributor

Take the information that follows with a grain of salt - **You're doing just fine how you're doing it, and don't need to change anything**.

I've found the strategy that works for me is, when I want to change Branch X, I start my feature branch at the HEAD of Branch X (i.e. `git checkout -b my-feature origin/branchx` -- then `add`, `commit`, etc). This strategy works perfectly with rebase-and-squash.

If my changes are destined for **both** Branch X and Branch Y, I start with the "merge base" between the branches (i.e. the latest commit common to both branches - `git checkout -b my-feature $(git merge-base --octopus origin/branchx origin/branchy)`). This is *only* so I don't introduce someone else's changes where they don't belong; say Bob broke the `test` branch and I don't want his commits - this merge-base strategy makes it so I don't grab Bob's commits. **This strategy isn't geared to easily work with rebase-and-squash.**

Comment: Thanks ! I just try your second solution with the "merge base", since I had to put my new feature on 'dev', then on 'test'. Unfortunately, I got the "out-of-sync" error again when I asked a pull request from 'dev' to 'test'. Keeping all my branches synchronized before pushing my new feature is really impossible ?

Comment: Using the merging strategy you're using `dev --> test --> main` it's always going to say that. Is it preventing your PR's from being able to be merged?